# Spark Scala sum up column elements of a dataset?

Tags: scala, count, apache-spark

I need to count the times a value example "2" is occurring in each column.

My dataset has this structure:

```
1 1 2 0 0 0 2 
0 2 0 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 0 2 2 2
0 0 0 0 1 1 2
```

I imported the file:

```
val ip = sc.textFile("/home/../data-scala.txt").map(line => line.split(" "))
```

How I can sum up the value equal to "2" in each column? i would expect to have as result an array of elements as

```
[0,2,1,0,1,1,3]
```

Comment: is this how u want your answer [0 ,2 ,1,0,1,1,3 ]  ?

Comment: You could [transpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390717/how-to-transpose-an-rdd-in-spark) your RDD and then count the `2`s using `transposedRdd.map(_.count(_ == "2"))`.

Comment: @PeterNeyens Transposition is expensive, not always feasible and there is really no need for that here.

Comment: Yes, I world like to get an array containing the count sum as [0 ,2 ,1,0,1,1,3 ]

Comment: My imported file is saved as an Array[Array[String]]

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
import breeze.linalg.DenseVector

def toInd(s: String): DenseVector[Int] = {
    DenseVector[Int](s.split(" ").map(x => if(x == "2") 1 else 0))
}

sc.textFile("/path/to/file").map(toInd).reduce(_ + _)
```

If you expect significant number of columns with sum equal zero you can replace `DenseVector` with `SparseVector`.

Above solution requires a new `DenseVector` object for each element of RDD. For a performance reason you may consider using `aggregate` and vector mutation:

```
def seqOp(acc: DenseVector[Int] , cols: Array[String]): DenseVector[Int] = {
    cols.zipWithIndex.foreach{ case (x, i) => if(x == "2") acc(i) += 1}
    acc
}

def combOp(acc1: DenseVector[Int], acc2: DenseVector[Int]): DenseVector[Int] = {
    acc1 += acc2
    acc1
}

val n = ip.first.length
ip.aggregate(DenseVector.zeros[Int](n))(seqOp, combOp)
```

You can easily replace `DenseVector` with a sparse one or `scala.collection.mutable.Map` if you want.

If you ask me it is rather ugly so I provide it only to make an answer complete.

Answer (score 2):

You could `map` the existence of `2` in each position first, giving you

```
[ 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ]
[ 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ]
[ 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ]
```

Then just do a reduce to gradually SUM each column.

Without involving Spark, it looks something like:

```
val list = Seq(
  Seq(1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2),
  Seq(0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  Seq(1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2),
  Seq(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2)
)

list.
   map(_.map(v => if(v == 2) 1 else 0)).
   reduce((a,b) => a.zip(b).map(t => t._1 +t._2 ))
```

Finding the optimum version of this one-liner is probably a bit a code golf challenge.