# how to interchange columns and rows in a file using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

how to convert columns to rows and from rows to columns similar to transpose of matrix for the data present in the file.

for ex:-
input file:-

```
    aa ab ac ad ae af ag
    ba bb bc bd be bf bg
    ca cb cc cd ce cf cg
```

output file:-

```
   aa ba ca
   ab bb cb
   ac bc cc
   ad bd cd
   ae be ce
   af bf cf
   ag bg cg
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the question here:
[How to transpose an RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390717/how-to-transpose-an-rdd-in-spark)

You can convert the DataFrame back to an rdd by calling `df.rdd` and follow the same steps provided in the post about RDDs. 
If the DataFrame is small enough, his first example of a simple transform using `collect()` would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MrChristine but if we are having a file we don't the values present the file. so we cannot use seq(for all the values in the file).
correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @AnkushReddySugureddy How is it a problem in this scenario?

Comment: @AnkushReddySugureddy I don't follow your statement. The example using Seq() is used to generate a test dataset in the post. You should be able to follow the same workflow.