# Calculate Pearson Correlation on a Spark Dataset

Tags: java, rdd, apache-spark-ml, pearson-correlation

I have a JavaRDD which contains arrays of doubles. Now I want to calculate the pearson coefficient between each array. But if I convert the rdd to vectors and apply statistics.corr(), the function calculates for the columns but i want it to calculate for rows. Can anyone suggest a way to convert my data to columns so that i can apply corr() function on that?

Edit: The statistics.corr() function takes javardd < vector > as input.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to convert each row to an RDD[Double] and compare their combinations (manually or loops)

```
val seriesX: RDD[Double] = ... // row1
val seriesY: RDD[Double] = ... // row2 must have the same number of partitions and cardinality as seriesX
val correlation: Double = Statistics.corr(seriesX, seriesY, "pearson")
```

or you can try to transpose your RDD and pass the resulting rdd to the corr(..) - some ideas on transposing here - [How to transpose an RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390717/how-to-transpose-an-rdd-in-spark)

if you have multiple row/records though and you want corrrelations of each against others the matrix might be too big and both options might take too low (if not possible at all)