# How to transpose a JavaRDD in Spark using Java 8

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a tab delimited file with numbers (forming a matrix) and I want to transpose the values. I've seen the other question where there is a scala answer but I can't seem to make it work using Java.

Comment: Can you provide the Scala solution?

Comment: Its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390717/how-to-transpose-an-rdd-in-spark

Comment: What about packaging the Scala solution out to a JAR and import it in your solution to use?

Comment: My goal was to have a Java 8 solution for transposing the rdd after some other transformations.